# Converting int to binary String in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to convert an integer to a binary String (see code below). I've already looked at several similar code snippets, and can't seem to find the reason as to why this does not work. It not only doesn't produce the correct output, but no output at all. Can somebody please explain to me in detail what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* toBinaryString(int n) {
  char *string = malloc(sizeof(int) * 8 + 1);
  if (!string) {
    return NULL;
  }
  for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    string[i] = n & 1;
    n >> 1;
  }
  return string;
}

int main() {
  char* string = toBinaryString(4);
  printf("%s", string);
  free(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n >> 1;` has no effect

Comment: You should terminate the string with `'\0'`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How would I do that? Can I just write `string[32] = '\0'`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I change it to `n = n >> 1`, that still doesn't change the output.

Comment: Yes - or `string[sizeof(int) * 8] = '\0'`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I now terminate the string, but if I run the program I still get no output. :(

Comment: RalphBear Consider the advantages  of `sizeof n` vs. `sizeof(int)`: easier to code right, review and maintain.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
string[i] = n & 1;
```

is assigning integers `0` or `1` to `string[i]`. They are typically different from the characters `'0'` and `'1'`. You should add `'0'` to convert the integers to characters.

Also, as @EugeneSh. pointed out, the line

```
n >> 1;
```

has no effect. It should be

```
n >>= 1;
```

to update the `n`'s value.

Also, as @JohnnyMopp pointed out, you should terminate the string by adding a null-character.

One more point it that you should check if `malloc()` succeeded. (It is done in the function `toBinaryString`, but there is no check in `main()` before printing its result)

Finally, It doesn't looks so good to use a magic number `31` for the initialization of `for` loop while using `sizeof(int)` for the size for `malloc()`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* toBinaryString(int n) {
  int num_bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
  char *string = malloc(num_bits + 1);
  if (!string) {
    return NULL;
  }
  for (int i = num_bits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    string[i] = (n & 1) + '0';
    n >>= 1;
  }
  string[num_bits] = '\0';
  return string;
}

int main() {
  char* string = toBinaryString(4);
  if (string) {
    printf("%s", string);
    free(string);
  } else {
    fputs("toBinaryString() failed\n", stderr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for pointing out. I'll fix.

Comment: Would casting the result of `n & 1` to `char` have the same effect as adding `'0'` as you did here?

Comment: @RalphBear No. Casting won't change the value unless the old value doesn't fit in the range of the new type.

Answer (score 1):

The values you are putting into the string are either a binary zero or a binary one, when what you want is the *digit* 0 or the *digit* one. Try `string[i] = (n & 1) + '0';`. Binary 0 and 1 are non-printing characters, so that's why you get no output.

Comment: There are no output not just because 0 and 1 are non-printing characters. The first element in the array will be 0, and 0 is used as a string terminator, so actually there will be no output even when it is seen as binary.

Comment: Yes, very true @MikeCAT

Answer (score 1):

```
#define INT_WIDTH 32
#define TEST 1

char *IntToBin(unsigned x, char *buffer) {
    char *ptr = buffer + INT_WIDTH;
    do {
        *(--ptr) = '0' + (x & 1);
        x >>= 1;
    } while(x);
    return ptr;
}

#if TEST
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int n;
        char str[INT_WIDTH+1]; str[INT_WIDTH]='\0';
        while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
            puts(IntToBin(n, str));
        return 0;   
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.