# Splitting a String Into Equal Integers in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am trying to split a 16-length char array of 1's and 0's into 2 equal length integers for 8-bit binary conversion to decimal.

Example:
char* str = "0001011011110000"
Result Expected:

```
int s = 00010110;
int t = 11110000;
```

Full Code:
What it Does: The user inputs a string of DNA (ex: ATTCGG). If the string is not divisible by 4, it will pad extra characters using strcat(). Then it will convert each char to a two-bit string in the new char array xtr[64]. This array must then be converted into two equal length 8-bit binary integers to be converted into two decimal numbers that represent the DNA string. Basically DNA binary compression is the assignment.

```c
int main()
{
    char str[64];
    scanf("%s", str);
    int obe = strlen(str);
    int mod = obe % 4;
    if (mod != 0) {
        for (int i = mod; i > 0; i--) {
            strcat(str, "0");
        }
    }
    int j;
    char xtr[64] = "";
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(str); j++) {
        if (str[j] == 'A') {
            strcat(xtr, "0");
            strcat(xtr, "0");
        } else if (str[j] == 'T') {
            strcat(xtr, "0");
            strcat(xtr, "1");
        } else if (str[j] == 'C') {
            strcat(xtr, "1");
            strcat(xtr, "0");
        } else if (str[j] == 'G') {
            strcat(xtr, "1");
            strcat(xtr, "1");
        } else if (str[j] == '0') {
            strcat(xtr, "0");
            strcat(xtr, "0");
        }
    }
    
    int k = strlen(xtr) / 2;
    char ret[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        ret[i] = xtr[i];
    }
    
    char ter[64];
    for (int i = k + 1; i < strlen(xtr); i++) {
        ter[i] = xtr[i];  
    }
    int s = atoi(ret);
    int t = atoi(ter);
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s", xtr);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", s);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", t);
    
    
}
```

Result:
ATTCGG00
0001011011110000
10110
0

Problem: The second integer is not being converted correctly, and this code is very primitive. May need bitwise operators.

Comment: `ret[i]` writes to an uninitialized pointer which is obviously wrong. Apart from that, what "pointer casts"? There are no casts in the code posted. Please post complete code and exact compiler messages.

Comment: Two points about using `atoi()`: a) you must terminate the string you pass, b) it doesn't convert binary, for that you need `strtol()`.

Comment: How can I comment the full code on here?

Comment: You can click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75534066/edit) link under the question.

Comment: I edited the code to include the prints. This is a code section in a more complex code that converts letters to 1's and 0's. Then converts that char array of digits into equal-length integers for binary conversions

Comment: Welcome, note that [`strtol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=msvc-170) takes 3 arguments. You'' also need to allocate memory for `ret` (either dynamically, or by using a fixed array), and you need to terminate the string you created.

Comment: Because you guys are offering great suggestions, I'm going to release the full code so you can all see why this is a struggle. Btw thanks for the quick responses

Comment: I posted the full code and a base description of what it is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int parseBitChars(char* str, int bitCount) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i != bitCount; i++) ret = (ret << 1) | (str[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  char* str = "0001011011110000";

  // Parse whole string in one go
  printf("Value: %d\n", parseBitChars(str, 16)); // Value: 5872
  
  // Or split into bytes
  int a = parseBitChars(str, 8);
  int b = parseBitChars(str + 8, 8);
  printf("Bytes: %d %d\n", a, b); // Bytes: 22 240
}
```

Comment: Thanks EDD. I assume the reverse of that method is to input the two integers, inverse the bitwise operators, and return the char* array?

Comment: Haris, my code is very primitive, but it still took hours to write and perfect the top portion of converting letters to bit-strings and combining those strings. EDD is just helping with the final part of compressing the char array into two decimal numbers

Comment: @MatthewMcCoy First you need to allocate enough space for the string, then you can start from the smallest bit and place it at the end of the string (`x & 1 ? '1' : '0'` to get convert lowest bit to char). Then to move to the next bit you can do `x = x >> 1` and repeat, writing to the next last character. But all this is pretty  tedious to write yourself so I would reccomend finding some code online.

Comment: Nice suggestion, what would be some good search terms to put in my search when looking for online code. Like "convert bytes to strings in c"

Comment: @MatthewMcCoy https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069409/5798435

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revamped version of your code with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) {
    char str[ 32 + 1 ]; // Up to 32 bases (plus terminator)
    char xtr[ 64 + 1 ] = ""; // Expands to 64
    int obe;

    scanf( "%32s%n", str, &obe ); // Limit user entry

    for( int i = obe % 4; i > 0; i-- )
        strcat( str, "A" ); // Pad (with 'A') to multiple of 4

    // Convert bases to binary values in a string
    for( int j = 0; str[ j ]; j++ )
             if ( str[j] == 'A' ) strcat( xtr, "00" );
        else if ( str[j] == 'T' ) strcat( xtr, "01" );
        else if ( str[j] == 'C' ) strcat( xtr, "10" );
        else if ( str[j] == 'G' ) strcat( xtr, "11" );

    // Output in blocks of 8 digits.
    for( int k = 0, len = strlen( xtr ); k < len; k += 8 )
        printf( "%d - %.8s\n", k, xtr + k );

    return 0;
}
```

```
ATTCGG
0 - 00010110
8 - 11110000
```

---

Converting a DNA sequence to an intermediary string is unnecessary.

Fortuitously, the ASCII code for the letters 'A', 'C', 'G' and 'T' encode well enough in bit 1 and bit 2. Note: This *encoding* differs from yours, assigning different bit patterns to represent each base.

```
'A' = 0bxxxxx00x ==> 0 // 'x' == "don't care"
'C' = 0bxxxxx01x ==> 2
'G' = 0bxxxxx11x ==> 6
'T' = 0bxxxxx10x ==> 4
```

The downside is that conventional "ACGT" swaps the order of the last two bases.

This 'swap' can be 'unswapped' with a translation using a crafted 8 bit hexadecimal value.

Explore the following code and study the demonstration strings below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void demo( char *p ) { // chunks of bases into registers
    puts( p );
    while( *p ) {
//      unsigned char  asBits = 0; //  4 bases/chunk
//      unsigned short asBits = 0; //  8 bases/chunk
        unsigned int   asBits = 0; // 16 bases/chunk
//      unsigned long  asBits = 0; // 32 bases/chunk
        const int pack = sizeof(asBits) * 4;

        // The ASCII for each of ACGT is pretty fortunate; can be hashed to two bits 0-3.
        // 0xB4: (0b10110100) 4 pairs of bits crafted to correspond to "GTCA" (reversed for shifting.)
        // Note that T&G are swapped by that 'magic byte' to conform to conventional "ACGT"
        // "AND"ing with 6 masks for the two fortunate bits,
        // "0xB4" is right shifted 0, 2, 6 or 4 bits,
        // that is then masked (3&) for its lowest two bits.
        // 'A'->0b00, 'C'->0b01, 'G'->0b10' and 'T'->0b11
        // The accumulator is shifted and this pair OR'd where they belong.

        int i;
        for( i = pack; *p && i; p++, i-- )
            asBits = asBits<<2 | (3 & (0xB4>>(*p&6))); // using one of several mapping functions

        // Sequence may not be modulo 16, so tack on extra 0b00 to pad as needed
        asBits <<= i+i; // padding for stragglers

        // Playback for verification
        printf( "%0*X - ", pack/2, asBits );
        for( int j = pack+pack-2; j >= 0; j -= 2 )
            putchar( "ACGT"[(asBits>>j)&3] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}


int main( void ) {
/*
    Some bonus alternative translation functions
    char *cp;
#   define M1 "\0\1\3\2"[*cp>>1&3]
#   define M2 "\0\0\0\1\3\0\0\2"[*cp&7]
#   define M3 3&0x8340>>(*cp<<1&0xF)
#   define M4 3&0xB4>>(*cp&6)
    char *n = "0123";
    for( cp = "ACGT"; *cp; cp++ ) printf( "%c %c%c%c%c\n", *cp, n[M1], n[M2], n[M3], n[M4] );
*/
    demo( "TGCTTGCCTGCATGCA" ); // 16 bases
    demo( "TTGCTTGCCTGCATGCT" ); // 17 bases

    demo( "T" ); // 1-4 bases
    demo( "AT" );
    demo( "AAT" );
    demo( "AAAT" );
    // lots of bases
    demo( "CATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCAT" );

    return 0;
}
```

Output demonstration:

```
TGCTTGCCTGCATGCA
E7E5E4E4 - TGCTTGCCTGCATGCA

TTGCTTGCCTGCATGCT
F9F97939 - TTGCTTGCCTGCATGC
C0000000 - TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

T
C0000000 - TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AT
30000000 - ATAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAT
0C000000 - AATAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAT
03000000 - AAATAAAAAAAAAAAA

CATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCAT
4D34D34D - CATCATCATCATCATC
34D34D34 - ATCATCATCATCATCA
D34D34C0 - TCATCATCATCATAAA
```

Play around with this for a while.

---

**EDIT:**
Here's another version of the core processing that simultaneously converts batches of 4 bases to both a string of 1's and 0's, and shows a decimal equivalent.

```
    unsigned char four = 0;

    // Convert bases to binary values in a string
    int j = 0;
    while( str[ j ] ) {
             if ( str[j] == 'A' ) strcat( xtr, "00" ), four = (four << 2) | 0;
        else if ( str[j] == 'T' ) strcat( xtr, "01" ), four = (four << 2) | 1;
        else if ( str[j] == 'C' ) strcat( xtr, "10" ), four = (four << 2) | 2;
        else if ( str[j] == 'G' ) strcat( xtr, "11" ), four = (four << 2) | 3;

        if( ++j % 4 == 0 ) {
            printf( "%s - %3d\n", xtr, four );
            xtr[0] = '\0';
            four = 0;
        }
    }
```

```
ATTCGG
00010110 -  22
11110000 - 240
```

Comment: Fe203, your code is amazingly simple. The only issue is that my code doesn't require the code to be printed in blocks of 8. Those blocks of 8 in binary are converted to decimal. So  the output of the code should be: 22 240. I'm still going to use your first half for conversions, but the issue now is converting those byte blocks to decimals.

Comment: @MatthewMcCoy Thanks. Buried in the 2nd part of this answer is "shifting and OR'ing" to set bits (or not) in an 'accumulator'... It's unclear if conversion to a 'string' of 1's and 0's is necessary. It's possible to go direct from ACTG to setting bits in a byte, then printing that as a decimal value... Cheers!.